# multiple selection for elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

i want to make a query for elasticsearch where it search all names, now they way i am doing it it will search a single name and when i try to put multiple names, it return null because as a example we assume that the first name is "**john**", so it will search for john and find it.

Now if we select another name "**johnsson**" than it will search for **johnjohnsson**, which will always return empty.

Now how i can make the query to search for all the names which is selected.

```
                        'query_string' => array(
                        'default_field' => 'name',
                        'query' => $name[$i] // how to search multiple names
                    )
                );
            }


            $docs = $client->search($params);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `$name` variable is an array, you can simply try to send all the values separated by space, using this:

```
...
'query_string' => array(
    'default_field' => 'name',
    'query' => implode(" ", $name)
)
...
```

So if `$name` is an array that contains the terms `name1` and `name2`, then the query in your query string will be `name1 name2`

Comment: You are awesome, just simply awesome, thanks a lot :), Hope it will work for me :)